# How to combine multi sass files into one css file with grunt?

Tags: sass, gruntjs

Ok im using the current version of grunt and ask google a lot of but i cant find any help.

my gruntfile.js looks like:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    sass: {
        dev: {
            src: ['src/*.scss'],
            dest: 'src/css/main.css',
        },
    },
    watch: {
        sass: {
            // We watch and compile sass files as normal but don't live reload here
            files: ['src/*.scss'],
            tasks: ['sass'],
        },
        livereload: {
            // Here we watch the files the sass task will compile to
            // These files are sent to the live reload server after sass compiles to them
            options: { livereload: true },
            files: ['src/**/*'],
            //tasks: ['includes'],
        }
    }
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

grunt.registerTask('default',['watch']);
```

}

I want to combine all SASS files into one master.css file.

did i need the concat plugin to solve it?
can someone please show me a working example of the grunfile.js?

Comment: Why not just @import the files in a single file called master.scss? This will also allow you to specify import order which is a fundamental aspect of css compilation.

Comment: because i dont want to add or remove every file.

Comment: Then how will you specifiy import order?

Comment: i thought that it is possible without. to manage one file with a lot of imports is much work in a great project. a lot of new files could come in or out. some src destinations changed etc. hmm

Comment: ok, could you show me please your example with a main import file?

Comment: You could also think of that main file as a sort of outline for your project. I personally like that approach because it helps developers that come behind you understand why/how the css in your project is related. It feels very organized. I put an example in an answer.

Answer (score 2):

No need for a concat plugin. Here's an example of a main app file wherein all your sass files can be imported. There's an added benefit of organization and an inherent benefit of source order.

```
//
// App
// app.scss 
// 
// 1. Config
// 2. Mixins
// 3. Normalize
// 4. Fonts
// 5. BaseStyles
// 6. Modules
// 7. Views
//

//
// @Config
//
@import "config";

//
// @Mixins
//
@import "mixins/helpers";
@import "mixins/grid";

//
// @Normalize
//
@import "normalize";

//
// @Fonts
//
@import "fonts/icomoon";

//
// @BaseStyles
//
@import "base/resets";
@import "base/animate";
@import "base/typography";
@import "base/utility";
@import "base/links_and_controls";

//
// @Modules
//
@import "modules/preloader";
@import "modules/header";
@import "modules/footer";

//
// @Views
//
@import "views/common";
@import "views/index";
@import "views/schedule";
@import "views/news";
@import "views/news_detail";
@import "views/gallery";
@import "views/gallery_detail";
@import "views/teams";
@import "views/kyle";
@import "views/partners";
```

Comment: and in grunt this:         sass: {
            dist: {
                files: {
                    'src/css/main.css': 'src/scss/main.scss'
                }
            }
        }, right? this doesnt work. i created into the main.scss a @import 'src/test/test.scss' and changed something in it. the console is showing some changes etc. works. but the css is not creating

Comment: If you delete main.css from your destination directory and then run grunt, is main.css created?

Comment: yes, but if i make a change in a imported scss the sass task donst work well because the main.css becomes no refresh/new create

Comment: This is definitely an issue with your grunt setup, not sass. Also, sass recognizes files as partials when you prepend the filename with an uderscore. So you're import should be '_test.scss'.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use concat plugin for this, and first concatenate all the scss files into one master.scss and after that you sass plugin to compile sass code into css.

```
module.exports = function(grunt){
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    concat: {
      dist: {
        src: ['src/css/*.scss'],
        dest: 'src/css/master.scss',
      }
    },

    sass: {
      build: {
        files: {
          'dist/css/style.css': 'src/css/master.scss'
        }
      }
    }

  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['concat', 'sass']);
};
```

Comment: Thank you, Roy. Good gods, there's virtually nothing more obnoxious than asking "How can I do X?" (where X is a very sensible and reasonable use case), and getting nothing but, "You don't need X! You should Y!" and "X!? My hairdresser's neighbor's kid who does web development says that if you're not Z-ing you're wasting your time!" Yours is the only answer that not only ANSWERS THE BLOODY QUESTION, but also bothers to show it in context, in relation to the other default settings, and even with the task registration at the bottom. I assume ROY is an acronym for "Requires Only Yours"? Thanks! <3